# Error in redeploying .war after simple .jsp chages

Tags: jsp, jboss, war

I have a .war file. First I change the extension to .zip extract out a particular .jsp file and and then I make some small changes to it. I kept the original war file and following this link [How to unpackage and repackage a WAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269961/how-to-unpackage-and-repackage-a-war-file) and the suggestion in it say "Non programmatically, you can just open the archive using the 7zip UI to add/remove or extract/replace files without the structure changing. I didn't know it was a problem using other things until now :)". I tried this mechanism but I got the following error. I would like to solve this with minimal change ? What is the best possible manner?

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /mainpage.jsp(4,0) File "/function_files/config.jsp" not found
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:485)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1557)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:212)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:101)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:296)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```