# Updating a file in a url

Tags: java

Am new to this forum.Need your help on understanding how we can update a zip file in a URL.

We have a zip file which can be accessed with a URL.Eg http://domainname/filename.zip

I would need to update the contents in the filename.zip,i can see the filename.zip on the application server under the following directory
Eg:/stage/iam_im/iam_im.ear/user_console.war/app/filename.zip

It is a Java based application and its deployed on a weblogic Server,I just want to know,is it possible i can go directly to the file location and update the filename.zip or being a war file,should i do some packaging which am not sure of.

Thanks in Advance,
Antony

Comment: The best option would be to rebuild the application from source. If that is not possible you can try modifying the war file, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269961/how-to-unpackage-and-repackage-a-war-file If you just overwrite the zip your change will be lost when the app server redeploys the war

Comment: your question is a bit unclear: do you need to programatically update the contents of the zip or do you need to repack the war file with a new zip?

Comment: Thanks for the responses,am not looking programattically,as you said ,I just want to repack the war file with my new version of zip file

Answer (score -1):

This is an example to to copy another file into an existing zip using `java.nio.file.FileSystem` together with `Files.copy()`. It 'mounts' the zip using the ZipFileSystem Provider. Then you can just copy whatever you want into it. The changes seem to take place on `fs.close()`

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
Path myFilePath = Paths.get("c:/dump2/mytextfile.txt");

Path zipFilePath = Paths.get("c:/dump2/myarchive.zip");
try( FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null) ){
    Path fileInsideZipPath = fs.getPath("/mytextfile.txt");
    Files.copy(myFilePath, fileInsideZipPath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

You could as well use it to first get out the file you want to change and replace it in the 'mount' after you're done.

Comment: he is not asking about how to copy a file or how to update a file in a zip

Comment: "I would need to update the contents in the filename.zip" ...is he not?

Comment: ah, I agree it is somewhat ambiguous what the question is